# Why doesn't my tastypie cache get called?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm looking at the [tastypie caching docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/caching.html) and trying to set up my own simple caching thing, but the cache doesn't seem to get called.  When I visit http://localhost:8000/api/poll/?format=json, I get my tastypie generated json, but I don't get the output from the cache class.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.cache import NoCache
from .models import Poll


class JSONCache(NoCache):
    def _load(self):
        print 'loading cache'
        data_file = open(settings.TASTYPIE_JSON_CACHE, 'r')
        return json.load(data_file)

    def _save(self, data):
        print 'saving to cache'
        data_file = open(settings.TASTYPIE_JSON_CACHE, 'w')
        return json.dump(data, data_file)

    def get(self, key):
        print 'jsoncache.get'
        data = self._load()
        return data.get(key, None)

    def set(self, key, value, timeout=60):
        print 'jsoncache.set'
        data = self._load()
        data[key] = value
        self._save(data)


class PollResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Poll.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'poll'
        cache = JSONCache()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that Tastypie doesn't automatically cache lists, `tastypie.resources` around line `1027`:

```
def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):

    # ...

    # TODO: Uncached for now. Invalidation that works for everyone may be
    #       impossible.
    objects = self.obj_get_list(
        request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

    # ...
```

, whereas with details (around line `1050`):

```
def get_detail(self, request, **kwargs):

   # ...

   try:
       obj = self.cached_obj_get(
           request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

   # ...
```

... note that in the former snippet `obj_get_list` is called instead of `cached_obj_get_list`. Perhaps overriding `get_list` and using `cached_obj_get_list` would allow you to use cache here as well?

Now you probably would get output from your class for `http://localhost:8000/api/poll/<pk>/?format=json` (detail view) but not for `http://localhost:8000/api/poll/?format=json` (list view) by default.